# Drupal 8 migrate plugin - explanation needed

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I want to migrate data from custom table to book content type, however I have no idea how to achieve that.
This is my config\install\migrate.migration.book_content.yml file:

```
id: book_content
label: Book content
migration_group: example
source:
  plugin: book_content
  target: db_migration
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: article
  title: title
  uid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  sticky:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0
  status:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  'body/value': content
  'body/summary': excerpt
  'body/format': 
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: full_html
  # Use of the migration process plugin.
  # That will use the id map of the specified migration 
  # to retrieve the corresponding id ('source' parameter) in the destination database.
  field_description:
    plugin: migration
    source: body
```

src\Plugin\migrate\source\BookContent.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\docapi_migrate\Plugin\migrate\source\BookContent.
 */
namespace Drupal\example_migrate\Plugin\migrate\source;
use Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\source\SqlBase;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;
/**
 * Drupal 8 node from database.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "book_content"
 * )
 */
class BookContent extends SqlBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function query() {
    $query = $this->select('docapi_migrate', 'dm')
                  ->fields('dm', array('url', 'depth', 'body', 'meta'));
    return $query;
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function fields() {
    $fields = array(
      'url' => $this->t('Content url'),
      'depth' => $this->t('Depth of the content'),
      'body' => $this->t('Full text of the content'),
      'meta' => $this->t('yaml data'),
    );
    return $fields;
  }
```

However when I do:

```
drush migrate-import book_content
```

I get:

```
The drush command 'migrate-import book_content' could not be found.
```

I don't understand how this functions in BookContent.php work.
There should be the tags_field with is taxonomy reference, but I have no idea, where should I process the meta, so for example I get a list of Tags.
And when I have tags, how should I combine it, so the migration works.
I was searching via google for information, but nothing really make sense. How can I understand this?

Answer (score 0):

You namespace is set to `example_migrate`. It needs to be set to the name of your module, so unless the module is called "example_migrate" it cannot find the class.

Change the name space to match YOUR_MODULE_NAME.

```
namespace Drupal\YOUR_MODULE_NAME\Plugin\migrate\source;
```

More about namespaces can be found when Googling for [PSR0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/).